# SDL - Why moving the mouse changes button state?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm having a problem with the Simple Directmedia Layer library. The following code draws a block on the screen when a mouse button is pressed:

```
SDL_Event event;
while(running){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        while(event.button.state == SDL_PRESSED){

            SDL_PollEvent(&event);

            //where to draw                
            boxRect.x = event.motion.x;
            boxRect.y = event.motion.y;

            //Draw to screen
            SDL_FillRect(display,&boxRect,boxColor);
            SDL_Flip(display);
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

It works fine until I move the mouse, why moving the mouse makes `event.button.state` untrue?

How can I work with both simultaneously (i.e. keep drawing while the button is pressed)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're calling `SDL_PollEvent` (documented [here](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_PollEvent)) twice.  As said in the documentation:

> If event is not NULL, the next event is removed from the queue and
>   stored in the SDL_Event structure pointed to by event.

Rearranging your code a bit, like getting rid of the second `SDL_PollEvent`, creating the proper flow for clicking, moving, releasing and extracting rendering from the input pumping should give you something like this:

```
SDL_Event Event;
while(running)
{
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event))
    {
        switch(Event.type)
        {
            // Handle your drawing with a simple state machine:
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            {
                if(Event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    if(stateMachine == Released)
                    {
                        // ... begin drawing
                        stateMachine = Dragging
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            {
                if(stateMachine == Dragging)
                {
                    // ... update the extends of your rect
                }
            }
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            {
                if(Event.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    if(stateMachine != Released)
                    {
                        // ... finalize drawing... add the rect to a list? flush it?
                        stateMachine = Released;
                    }
                }
            }
            case SDL_QUIT:
            {
                running = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Outside of your event pumping, update the graphics
    SDL_FillRect(display,&boxRect,boxColor);
    SDL_Flip(display);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.button.state` is a bit mask. It is declared as a `char` which can hold eight bits representing different states of the buttons.

```
typedef struct{
  Uint8 type;
  Uint8 state;
  Uint16 x, y;
  Sint16 xrel, yrel;
} SDL_MouseMotionEvent;
```

More information here,

http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlgetmousestate.html
http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlmousemotionevent.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't understand why it affects the other parts of the structure. Could you provide an example of code that would draw a block while the mouse is pressed down? I updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to emartel's answer, it's working as expected, here's the code:

```
SDL_Event event;
int drawing = 0;

while(running){
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)){
        switch(event.type){

            //starts drawing when any mouse button is pressed
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                drawing = 1;
                boxRect.x = event.button.x;
                boxRect.y = event.button.y;
            break;


            //keeps drawing while no button is released
            case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
                if(drawing == 1){
                    boxRect.x = event.motion.x;
                    boxRect.y = event.motion.y;
                }
            break;


            //stops drawing when any button is released
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                drawing = 0;
            break;


            case SDL_QUIT:
                running = 0;
            break;

        }

    }

    //draws to screen
    if(drawing == 1){
        SDL_FillRect(display,&boxRect,boxColor);
        SDL_Flip(display);
    }
}
```